# Integration in state space models - Is this internal integration?

Tags: integration, control-theory, optimal-control, simulation, linear-control

I'm reading a book labeled "Predictive Control System Design and Implementation Using MATLAB®, by. Liuping Wang." It's an easy book for basic understanding in linear Model Predictive Control.

Anyway! According to the book, the book is learning out Predictive Control with integration included in a augmented state space model:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x_m(k+1) \\ 
y(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_m & 0_m^T\\ 
C_mA_m & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x_m(k) \\ 
y(k)
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
B_m\\ 
C_m B_m
\end{bmatrix} \Delta u(k)
$$

$$y(k) = \begin{bmatrix}
0_m & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x_m(k) \\ 
y(k)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $$\Delta x_m(k+1) = x_m(k+1) - x_m(k)$$
$$\Delta u(k) = u(k) - u(k-1)$$
$$\Delta x_m(k) = x_m(k) - x_m(k-1)$$

**Question:**

How can this be integration? Why cant the augmented model be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_m(k+1) \\ 
y(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_m & 0_m^T\\ 
C_mA_m & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_m(k) \\ 
y(k)
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
B_m\\ 
C_m B_m
\end{bmatrix} u(k)
$$

$$y(k) = \begin{bmatrix}
0_m & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_m(k) \\ 
y(k)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Why is $\Delta$ important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start of with the dynamics

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x(k+1) &= A\,x(k) + B\,u(k) \\
y(k) &= C\,x(k)
\end{align}\right. \tag{1}
$$

so

$$
y(k+1) = C\,x(k+1) = C\,A\,x(k) + C\,B\,u(k) \tag{2}
$$

but your augmented model would give

$$
y(k+1) = C\,A\,x(k) + C\,B\,u(k) + \color{red}{y(k)} \tag{3}
$$

which is incorrect (at least inconsistent with the dynamics you started with).

By instead using $\Delta x(k) = x(k) - x(k-1)$ and $\Delta u(k) = u(k) - u(k-1)$, so $x(k) = \Delta x(k) + x(k-1)$ and $u(k) = \Delta u(k) + u(k-1)$, then equation $(2)$ can also be written as

$$
y(k+1) = C\,A\,\left(\Delta x(k) + x(k-1)\right) + C\,B\,\left(\Delta u(k) + u(k-1)\right). \tag{4}
$$

When using the definition of $y(k)$ and $x(k)$ then the terms of equation $(4)$ containing $x(k-1)$ and $u(k-1)$ can be rewritten as

$$
C\,A\,x(k-1) + C\,B\,u(k-1) = C\,x(k) = y(k) \tag{5}
$$

therefore

$$
y(k+1) = y(k) + C\,A\,\Delta x(k) + C\,B\,\Delta u(k). \tag{6}
$$

---

One could of course also augment the model by using equation $(2)$, which gives

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x(k+1) \\ y(k+1)
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ C\,A & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x(k) \\ y(k)
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\ C\,B
\end{bmatrix} u(k) \tag{7}
$$

but in this case there is not really any direct integration in $y$, since normally for integration you have something of the following form $y(k+1) = y(k) + \Delta y(k)$, for example in [forward Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) you have $\Delta y(k) = \Delta t\,\dot{y}(k)$. This is not the case in equation $(7)$, but is in equation $(6)$.

Comment: And this will give me internal integration in my discrete model?

Comment: Does this works with time continuous too?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson In continues time you can just find the derivative of $y$, since integrating the derivative gives $y$ back again. Doing so will therefore, in terms of matrices, give equation $(7)$ in continues time. Namely the derivative of $y$ is not directly a function of itself.

Comment: and the C-matrix will be the same, Only the A-matrix missing the "1" matrix.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Yes, since the added state is still already $y$.

Comment: I saw that when I do this in continuous time, I get a pole at 0.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That is because of the fact that the dynamics does not specify $y(0)$. This also happens for the discrete case, but in that case the pole lies at one.

Comment: Do you recommend any method to do integration with prediction with state space models?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson what do you mean by prediction? Future values of the output of the system or for the entire state (like in the prediction step of a Kalman filter)?

Comment: But you told me above that "but in this case there is not really any direct integration in y". So that model above is not integration at all?

Comment: Is it worth to have integration on MPC?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I said that about $(7)$, but your augmented model with $\Delta x$ and $\Delta u$ does add an integral. One could also apply the integral to the input, so $u(k)=u(k-1)+\Delta u(k)$, so with $u(k-1)$ a state and $\Delta u(k)$ the input, together with $(1)$. If the input is of the same size as the output one can probably do a similarity transformation between this and the dynamics with $(6)$.

Comment: Also I do not have any practical experience with MPC, but maybe the augmented model with the integral in the output might lend itself well for certain inequality constraints in $\Delta x$ and $\Delta u$.

Comment: I understand that when $u(k-1)$ is the same as the current $u(k)$, then the input $\Delta u(k)$ is going to be $0$. If I compute the predicted inputs $U(k) = [u(1), u(2), .... , u(n)]$, Will the last predicted input be very large due to the integration? I have a repository about pratical control if you are interested. I have upload a Linear Quadratic Gaussian Integral controller where the model is estimated from data. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Practical-Control-Engineering/

Comment: I think you have forgotten a $1$ at the $A$ matrix.